# Plot rows of df on Plotly

Tags: dataframe, plotly, subplot

The df is like this:

```
          X             Y            Label
0  [16, 37, 38]  [7968, 4650, 3615]   0.7
1  [29, 37, 12]  [4321, 4650, 1223]   0.8
2  [12, 2, 445]  [1264, 3456, 2112]   0.9
```

This should plot three lines on the same plot with labels as continuous variables. What is the fastest & simplest way to plot it using `plotly`?

Comment: subplots or traces?  first comment is subplots which means a graph per row, second comment is three lines on same plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking *This should plot three lines on the same plot* as the requirement. (Which is inconsistent with *where I want subplots from each row of the df*)

Simple case of create a trace for each row,  using https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html to prepare x and y

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "X": [[16, 37, 38], [29, 37, 12], [12, 2, 445]],
        "Y": [[7968, 4650, 3615], [4321, 4650, 1223], [1264, 3456, 2112]],
        "Label": [0.7, 0.8, 0.9],
    }
)

go.Figure(
    [
        go.Scatter(
            x=r["X"].explode(), y=r["Y"].explode(), name=str(r["Label"].values[0])
        )
        for _, r in df.groupby(df.index)
    ]
)
```

[image]

#### with continuous color defined by **label**

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.colors import sample_colorscale
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "X": [[16, 37, 38], [29, 37, 12], [12, 2, 445]],
        "Y": [[7968, 4650, 3615], [4321, 4650, 1223], [1264, 3456, 2112]],
        "Label": [0.1, 0.5, 0.9],
    }
)

fig = px.scatter(x=[0], y=[0], color=[.5], color_continuous_scale="YlGnBu")


fig = fig.add_traces(
    [
        go.Scatter(
            x=r["X"].explode(),
            y=r["Y"].explode(),
            name=str(r["Label"].values[0]),
            line_color=sample_colorscale("YlGnBu", r["Label"].values[0])[0],
            showlegend=False
        )
        for _, r in df.groupby(df.index)
    ]
)

fig
```

Comment: This works but I want continuous variable legend. Something like the colorbar

Comment: Which variable is continuous for color x, y or label?

Comment: variable label is a continuous variable. Basically I want a colour bar kind of thing in the label and not discrete labels.

Comment: ok updated to do this - second part of answer